# Is all escaping of encodeURIComponent really needed?

Tags: javascript, security, url, url-parameters, websecurity

I understand that `encodeURIComponent` is needed to prevent ambiguity when parsing url and avoid encoding issues. But what I want to ask - it all its encoding really needed if I'm going to form a query parameter (exactly it, not the other part of url)? For example, you may see that both following urls are working correctly:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=[1,{"a":"b"}]
https://www.google.com/search?q=%5B1%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%22b%22%7D%5D
```

[image: screenshot]

I just want to make more beautiful url and for that purpose I want to revert escaping of braces, quotes, colons and comma. Is such update safe? Can it break something, or will it allow to do some kind of attacks on the site?

```js
function beautifulEncode(s) {
  return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/%../g, m => ({
    "%5B": '[',
    "%5D": ']',
    "%7B": '{',
    "%7D": '}',
    "%2C": ',',
    "%3A": ':',
    "%22": '"',
  }[m] || m))
}

console.log(beautifulEncode(JSON.stringify([1, {a: "b"}])))
console.log(beautifulEncode(JSON.stringify([1, {'A&B+1': "I'm here"}])))

console.log(beautifulEncode("&hello world"))
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1148970/178988)

Comment: Check what happens if the query is `&hello world`.

Comment: @root, `https://www.google.com/search?q=%26hello%20world` - what's wrong? Neither `&` nor space's encoding is unaffected by proposed change.